# Basic Arduino\c nested lists for loops diffculties

Tags: c#, python, arduino, nested, latitude-longitude

I am working on a self arduino project, trying to get my code work for the last 3 days without any success.
I wrote the code in python to get the main idea working and than trying rewrite it to arduino based system.

```
self=[[1.23456,2.23456]]
list=[[1.75087,2.03031],[1.78371,2.04686],[1.78413,2.04696],[1.79346,2.09962]]

counter=0
for i in list:
      if abs(self[0]-i[0])<0.00165 and abs(self[1]-i[1])<0.00165:
          counter=1
      else:
          counter=0

print counter
```

the idea should be very simple, first you have the self (longtitude/latitude), and a listed of nested lists.
the for loop should check every item in list and the distance(abs) of it from the self.

I'm a beginner in c# and arduino, and just couldn't get the logic to get it to work.

appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arduino has the look of C:

```
double selfLat = 1.23456;
double selfLon = 2.23456;

double list[4][2] = {
  {1.75087,2.03031},
  {1.78371,2.04686},
  {1.78413,2.04696},
  {1.79346,2.09962}
};

int counter=0;
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
  int test1 = abs(selfLat - list[i][0]) < 0.00165;
  int test2 = abs(selfLon - list[i][1]) < 0.00165;
  if ( test1 && test2 ) counter = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good except that self should be a list rather than a list of lists. Secondly, print counter within the loop.

```
self=[1.23456,2.23456]
list=[[1.75087,2.03031],[1.78371,2.04686],[1.78413,2.04696],[1.79346,2.09962]]

counter=0
for i in list:
    if abs(self[0]-i[0])<0.00165 and abs(self[1]-i[1])<0.00165:
        counter=1
    else:
        counter=0
    print counter
```

Comment: Thanks, this is not what i meant. i know that this code works, i want to write this code for arduino use, and i dont know how to do it. how do i write the same function for arduino platform?

Comment: No clue about arduino. I am just guessing here: if arduino does not support list of lists, then you have to find an alternative, maybe a list of data structures?